# Is there a way to aggregate values in a column in sqlite in one-to-many relationship into array?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Is there a way to aggregate values in a column in sqlite in one-to-many relationship into array?
For example, I have 2 tables like this:

```
Artists:
ArtistId    name
1            AC/DC
2            Accept

Albums:
AlbumId ArtistId Title
1         1        For Those About To Rock We Salute You
2         1        Let There Be Rock
3         2        Balls to the Wall
4         2        Restless and Wild
```

When I just do a query with a join:

```
SELECT
   Name,
   Title
FROM
   artists
JOIN albums USING(ArtistId)
WHERE artists.ArtistId = 1;
```

I get:
[image]

I found out that I can do `group_concat`:

```
SELECT
   Name,
   GROUP_CONCAT(Title)
FROM
   artists
JOIN albums USING(ArtistId)
WHERE artists.ArtistId = 1;
```

To concatenate all values together:
[image]

But I still have to parse the coma-separated string with titles: `For Those About To Rock We Salute You,Let There Be Rock` in the code to get the array of titles for each artist.

I use Python and I'd prefer to get something like a tuple for each row:
(name, titlesArray)

A much easier way in this case for me would be to use json.loads and json.dumps functions to save all the "many" array members into the same row in the same table, instead of using the recommended way for databases to save values in different tables and then use joins to retrieve them: the "many" values is an array on the object, and it's just much easier to save and get them using just 2 functions: json.loads and json.dumps, compared to manually saving the "many" values into a separate table, create binding to the "one" value, then use group_concat to concat them into a string, and then parse it more to actually get my array back.

Is it possible to get an array of values, or do I have to do `group_concat` and parse the string?

Comment: Post your expected json output to clarify what you want.

Comment: I don't want json, I want to get python objects from the database in the end. json could be one way to store it in the database, and I don't particularly like to store it that way in the database, it doesn't feel right. I just want to persist objects in the database and then get them back without writing a lot of code and doing a bunch of hacks in the code like converting python arrays to json, and then parsing back again.

Comment: SQLite does not support arrays.

Comment: Yep, I understand. What do I do then to persist objects in SQLite database and then load them back in from the database? My objects vary from simple objects with only basic data types in them such as integers and strings to complex objects that consist of other objects that have arrays of objects.

Comment: You can't persist objects in SQLite. You can store numeric and text values and binary data with the BLOB data type. The objects that you have in your app must be mapped to simpler data in one of the supported data types, or as you already know, you must create json strings for each one of the objects.

Answer (score 2):

You might not be able to receive an array from sqlite straight away, but you can achieve the result with a very little edit on your query and a single line in python.

`group_concat` supports a custom delimiter that you can use later to split the entries.

Let's assume you have something like this:

```py
from typing import Typle
import sqlite3

def connect(file: str = None) -> sqlite3.Connection:
    connection = None

    try:
        connection = sqlite3.connect(file)
    except sqlite3.Error:
        raise

    return connection


def select(connection: sqlite3.Connection) -> Tuple(str, str)):
    entry = None

    try:
        sql = """
        SELECT
            Name,
            GROUP_CONCAT(Title)
        FROM artists
        JOIN albums USING(ArtistId)
        WHERE artists.ArtistId = 1;
        """
        cursor.execute(sql, parameters)

        reply = cursor.fetchone()
        if reply is not None:
            entry = reply

    except sqlite3.Error:
        raise 
    finally:
        cursor.close()  

    return entry
```

that you can use to connect to the database and select from it like so:

```py
connection = connect(r"/path/to/file.sqlite3")
if connection is not None:
    entry = select(connection)
    connection.close()
```

It is not important if your query is inside a function or not, the important concept is that you are using python to do this query, and you can add some code to manipulate the values.

As you can see [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group_concat/) `group_concat` accepts a separator that you can use to arbitrarily separate values.

Your new select function could be something like:

```py
def select(connection: sqlite3.Connection) -> Tuple(str, Tuple(str, ...)):
    entry = None
    separator = r"|"

    try:
        sql = f"""
        SELECT
            Name,
            GROUP_CONCAT(Title, {separator})
        FROM artists
        JOIN albums USING(ArtistId)
        WHERE artists.ArtistId = 1;
        """
        cursor.execute(sql, parameters)

        reply = cursor.fetchone()
        if reply is not None:
            reply[1] = reply[1].split(separator)
            entry = reply

    except sqlite3.Error:
        raise 
    finally:
        cursor.close()  

    return entry
```

Without changing how you use this function, you would now have a tuple with all the titles.

Another idea you'd like to consider is to do a more specific select query, like:

```sql
select albums.Title
from albums
where albums.ArtistId = 1;
```

In this case, you can have a list of titles using: `cursor.fetchall()`.
Of course the band name should be asked separately in this case.